# how to count the number of values in an column column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a column which has monthly income of persons with data like <50,000 , 50,000 to 1,00,000 & so on. I want to count the number of each occurrences of <50,000 in that particular column. 
i tried using =COUNTIF(X2:X123,"<50,000") but its giving me 0 every time.

data in table looks like this:
    <50,000
    <50,000
    <50,000
    50,000- 1,50,000
    <50,000
    <50,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate the "," from your formula. With that comma in the "50,000", Excel reads it as text, not a number.

**Edit based on clarification** - to count the number of times that a text string appears, you need to use this:

```
=Countif(A1:A2,"=asdf")
```

Or alternatively just

```
=Countif(A1:A2,"asdf")
```

The problem here is that when excel reads "<50000" it actually thinks you want to do a value comparison. After testing see now that "<50,000" actually does properly convert "50,000" to a number. I assume this is because Excel normally takes a string like 'OPERATER_NUMBER' and breaks off the operater and the number part of a string, and then converts that string to a number. So, the comma is properly eliminated.

So if you want to see how many times the string "50,000" appears, use this:
    =Countif(A1:A2,"="&"<50,000")

Actually to be clear, you could also just do 
    =Countif(A1:A2,"=<50,000")

But when I read it this way, I read it as "Equal to or lesser than 50,000". Though excel appears to know what to do with it. In any case, I think separating the "=" from the "<50,000" is more clear.

Comment: I tried this =COUNTIF(X2:X123,"50000") its still not working. i also tried =COUNTIF(X2:X123,"<50000") not working. My data has values as <50,000 so i need to have < right so that it identifies the full value & then count.

Comment: =COUNTIF(X2:X123,"<50000") should work, as long as you have some cells which are less than 50,000. Note that if your data is considered "text" by excel due to formatting, it will read your column X as text values (and therefore it cannot find a number "smaller than" a string of text. To check if your cells are considered go to the data ribbon, select "text to columns" and click "Finish". This will convert "numeric text" from text into actual numbers.

Comment: i want <50,000 to be treated as a single string & then count the number of times "<50,000" is occuring in that particular column. I dont want to display any quantity  less than 50,000, <50,000 is itself a value whose count i want to get

Comment: I have edited my response - I tested and confirmed that it does what you are asking.